# Erro para compilar código OpenGL

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

Boa Tarde, uso *`linux`* e estou aprendendo *`OpenGL`*, mas quando eu vou *compilar* o meu código da esse erro:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

o unico código que tenho é esse:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
```

e o código que usei para compilar foi esse: *g++ main.cpp -o main*

Já instalei as libs:`libglm-dev` e `libglew-dev`.

Como poderia resolver.

Uso *linux mint 19.3*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Falta colocar as opções do linker no gcc:

`g++ main.cpp -o main -lGLEW`

E também definir uma função `int main()`

Para um projeto completo também vai precisar de linkar pelo menos OpenGL com `-lGL`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, desculpa não ter respondido antes, tive uns probleminhas aqui, não sabia que precisava do método main para compilar, valeu

Comment: Pra compilar um executável com a opção `-o` tem que definir `int main()`. Só quando compila um object file de uma eventual dependência que não precisa.